# Submit extjs Form on button click

Tags: forms, extjs, submit

I am new for extjs.
I am having one store in which i am having some data coming from json file.
I have created a form.
i want to save new data in that store through form.
How can I create button and submit form on that button's click?
please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ExtJS 4 and your form is bound to a 'model' instance, then you get get a reference to your model in your buttons click handler and call:

```
model.save();
```

Which will send a post request to the url defined as the proxy on the model class.

Post your code and perhaps we can be some more direct help.

Answer (score 0):

In the API of ExtJS is a good example on how to create a [`Ext.form.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel) with a button. When you click on this button the form gets [submitted](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit).
This example doesn't work because it doesn't submit to a page but it is very configurable.

Snippet of the button+handler:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Submit',
    handler: function() {
        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
        if (form.isValid()) {
            form.submit({
                url: '', //this is the url where the form gets submitted
                success: function(form, action) {
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                },
                failure: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]
```